# Continuity of a linear operator when functional is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let's consider two Banach spaces -- $X$ and $Y$.
>    We define a linear operator $T: X \to Y$. For all $y^* \in Y^*$  the functional $x \mapsto y^*(Tx)$ is continuous on $X$.

Now I need to deduce that $T$ is continuous.

---

I thought of showing that $T$ is bounded. However I don't know where to start. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: Can we use the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yes we can.

Comment: Closed graph? $\ $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $\phi \in Y^*$, define $T^*(\phi) \in X^*$ by $[T^*(\phi)](x) = \phi(T(x))$.
The collection of maps 
$$
\mathcal F = \{T^*(\phi) : \phi \in Y^*, \|\phi\| = 1\}
$$
satisfies the hypothesis of the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle).

Comment: This collection satisfies the uniform boundedness principle, because $\| T^*(\phi) \| = \| \phi(T(x)) \| < \infty$, because of our assumption?

Comment: @Hendrra it is not true that $\|T^*(\phi)\| = \|\phi(T(x))\|$.  It is true that $\|T^*(\phi)\| < \infty$ because of our assumption

Comment: Is it true that $\| T^*(\phi) \| = \| \phi(T) \|$? We defined $T^*(\phi)$ this way, didn't we?

Comment: @Hendrra $\phi \circ T$ is not the same thing as $\phi(T)$, and the function $x \mapsto \phi(T(x))$ is not the same as $\phi(T(x))$.

Comment: $\phi$ is a functional so it needs an element from $Y$, yes? $T$ is a map from $X$ to $Y$ thus the argument of $\phi$ can be $Tx$. Am I right? Thus by the assumption $\phi$ is bounded since continuous.

Comment: @H $\phi$ is an element of $Y^*$, which is to say that it is bounded/continuous functional. $\phi$ is continuous by the definition of $Y^*$.  I am not sure what you're trying to say here

Comment: Sorry for keep asking but I would really like to understand this problem. $T^* \in X^*$ thus $T^*: X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$(for example). So how can $\phi$ be an argument of $T^*$?

Comment: @Hendrra It is not true that $T^* \in X^*$. Instead, we have $T^*: Y^* \to X^*$.  It is true that for any $\phi \in Y^*$, $T^*(\phi) \in X^*$.